# Auth::check always return false while Auth::attempt true in Laravel 10.10

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have 2 Blade files: `login.blade.php` and `dashboard.blade.php`.
In `LoginController`, I am using `Auth::attempt()` to authenticate the user and redirect to the dashboard if successful.

For the Dashboard, I have one more middleware to check the login status. After I successfully logged in and navigated to the dashboard, it took me back to the login page. That means the login status is false.

In the `login` function. If I try `return Auth::user()` right after using `attempt` it works. But when checking in middleware or another route, `Auth::check()` returns false.

web.php

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function () {
  Route::get('login', 'PublicController@index')->name('login');
  Route::post('login', 'PublicController@login')->name('login.post');
});

Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers', 'middleware' => ['auth.login']], 
 function () {
   Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('dashboard.index');
});
```

login function in Controller

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $data = $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if(Auth::attempt($data)) {
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        if(!$request->login_as || Auth::user()->role != $request->login_as) {
            return back()->withErrors(['message' => 'False!'])->withInput();
        }
        return redirect()->intended(route('dashboard.index'));
    }
    return back()->withErrors(['message' => 'False!'])->withInput();
}
```

AuthCheck.php middleware - I have added this middleware to `$middlewareAliases`

```
class AuthCheck
{
   public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
   {
     if(!Auth::check()) {
        return redirect('login');
     }

    return $next($request);
   }
}
```

auth.php config and session config

```
//Auth config
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Account::class,
    ]
]
//Session config
{
 "driver": "file",
 "lifetime": "120",
 "expire_on_close": false,
 "encrypt": false,
 "files": "/Users/chanhhuynh/Documents/Freelance/rental- 
        management/storage/framework/sessions",
 "connection": null,
 "table": "sessions",
 "store": null,
 "lottery": [
    2,
    100
 ],
 "cookie": "laravel_session",
 "path": "/",
 "domain": null,
 "secure": null,
 "http_only": true,
 "same_site": "lax"
}
```

I have searched and tried some way but still not work. Is there any solution to fix it? Thanks